# How can I install redir on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, software-installation

I need to install `redir` to forward traffic on CentOS 7. Tried

```
yum install redir
```

and also

```
yum search redir
```

they don't find anything, so how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package can be found here:

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/nux-misc-x86_64/redir-2.2.1-7.el7.nux.x86_64.rpm.html

Install Howto

Create the repository config file `/etc/yum.repos.d/nux-misc.repo:`

```
[nux-misc]
name=Nux Misc
baseurl=http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/misc/el7/x86_64/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/RPM-GPG-KEY-nux.ro
```

---

Install redir rpm package:

```
# yum --enablerepo=nux-misc install redir
```

Requires:

```
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit)

libwrap.so.0()(64bit)

rtld(GNU_HASH)
```